# How can I have Linux execute a bash script when a specific disk is hotswapped in?

Tags: linux, scripting, ubuntu-14.04, udev, hotswap

I have a set of hard drives which are rotated for offsite backup.  There are several steps that need to be performed when one of the disks is reinserted which I've rolled into a simple bash script.  I'd like to execute the script automatically when one of the disks is hot-swapped in.

Ideally I'd have a list of disk-id's (`/dev/disk/by-id/...`) for the disks which should trigger the script; when one of them is inserted the script would be ran and the ID of the specific disk would be passed in as a parameter.  As an alternative it would be good enough to have a copy of the script per-disk and have each script ran for its respective disk.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, and have been skimming similar questions related to USB drives and am looking at `udev` and `hotplug` as the two systems that I'll likely need to use, but was hoping someone may be able to point me to a specific succinct solution for my needs.

Comment: Write an UDEV rule for that.

Comment: And when writing that udev rule, have a look at the system udev rules how the entries in disk/by-id are created. At least on my Slackware system they are created using variables like `$env{ID_SCSI_COMPAT}` and `$env{ID_SERIAL}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual approach to udev rule writing is to find something similar to what I need in `/lib/udev` and complement it with a google search or a quick look at the man pages.

For your case, most of the mojo can be found in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`. I came up with this rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="XXXXXXXX", PROGRAM="/opt/bin/myscript $env{ID_SERIAL}"
```

You would need one rule for each drive, and your script receives the drive serial as a parameter.

I'm only using the drive serial here, that should be enough but you can rebuild the whole ID as seen in `/dev/disk/by-id` with this string:

```
$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}
```

To check the drive's serial number you can use:

```
udevadm info -n /dev/disk/by-id/XXXXXXXX | grep -i SERIAL
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this'll be exactly what I need--I'll accept the answer after I get the chance to test it during the next rotation

Comment: I strongly suggest that you test this (or any advice from random people on the internet) before you deploy it on production. [It's quite easy to test udev rules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Testing_rules_before_loading)

Comment: Thanks gnp, that link looks useful.  I'd planned on having the rule run a basic 'hello world' bash script to verify that it would execute with IDs as expected

Comment: This is working well; I had a problem running my rule too early--`ENV{ID_SERIAL}` wasn't matching.  Renaming the file `99-local.rules` (running it last) solved that.